# nginx + php-fpm - where are my $_GET params?

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, kohana

I have a strange problem here. I just moved from apache + mod_php to nginx + php-fpm. Everything went fine except this one problem.

I have a site, let's say example.com. When I access it like `example.com?test=get_param` `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` is `/?test=get_param` and there is a `$_GET['test']` also.

But when I access `example.com/ajax/search/?search=get_param` `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` is `/ajax/search/?search=get_param` yet there is no `$_GET['search']` (there is no `$_GET` array at all).

I'm using Kohana framework. which routes `/ajax/search` to controller, but I've put `phpinfo()` at `index.php` so I'm checking for `$_GET` variables before framework does anything (this means that disapearing get params aren't frameworks fault).

My nginx.conf is like this

```
worker_processes  4;
pid        logs/nginx.pid;
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}
http {
    index index.html index.php;
    autoindex on;
    autoindex_exact_size off;
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    server_names_hash_bucket_size 128;
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  logs/access.log  main;
    error_log   logs/error.log   debug;

    sendfile        on;
    tcp_nopush      on;
    tcp_nodelay     off;

    keepalive_timeout  2;

    gzip  on;
    gzip_comp_level 2;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml     application/xml+rss text/javascript;


    include sites-enabled/*;
}
```

and example.conf is like this

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name www.example.com;
  rewrite ^ $scheme://example.com$request_uri? permanent;
}




server {
    listen   80;
    server_name example.com;
    root /var/www/example/;

    location ~ /\. {
        return 404;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        /usr/local/nginx/conf/fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~* ^/(modules|application|system) {
        return 403;
    }

        # serve static files directly
        location ~* ^.+.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html|xml|txt)$ {
                access_log        off;
                expires           30d;
        }
}
```

fastcgi_params is like this

```
fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;

fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx/$nginx_version;

fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;

# PHP only, required if PHP was built with --enable-force-cgi-redirect
fastcgi_param  REDIRECT_STATUS    200;


fastcgi_connect_timeout 60;
fastcgi_send_timeout 180;
fastcgi_read_timeout 180;
fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
fastcgi_buffers 4 256k;
fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
fastcgi_intercept_errors on;


fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING    $query_string;
fastcgi_param PATH_INFO       $fastcgi_path_info;
```

What is the problem here?

By the way there are few more sites on the same server, both Kohana based and plain php, that are working perfectly.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

You are not passing get arguments in your [try_files](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#try_files) call

in the question:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
}
```

Should be:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
```

You can use either [$query_string](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#.24query_string) or [$args](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#.24args), they are equivalent - except `$query_string` is readonly (or alternatively, `$args` can be updated by any other logic you may wish to add)

Comment: +1 Slim's very own documentation [is wrong](http://docs.slimframework.com/).

Comment: ^ ditto; spent hours trying to get the wretched thing sorted for another project. Thank you ad7six.

Comment: From the latest Slim3 documentation: `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;`

Comment: What if we are using php-fpm instead of fastcgi? We can't use the config in fastcgi.conf to retrieve the variable name "$query_string"

Answer (score 4):

```
location / {
   try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try my rules:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @koh;
}

location @koh {
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /var/www/example/index.php;
    include        /usr/local/nginx/conf/fastcgi_params;
}
```

Also delete duplicated "fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING" in fastcgi_params.

Comment: This doesn't work. On `ajax/search` it gives 500 error, on example.com it pops up download window and downloaded file is index.php

Comment: Anyway, I've come up with an answer, `try_files $uri $uri/ index.php;` must be `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args; #or /index.php?$query_string, mind the '?'`, but it would be nice that someone explained this :)

Comment: btw, error log for your config, alvosu, says `could not find named location @koh`.

Comment: Sorry, I was made a mistake. I corrected "location".